# How to save file from app bundle to disk

Tags: cocoa, swift3, nsdata, xcode8, nsbundle

I have a file that's in my NSBundle, and I'd like the user to be able to save it anywhere they'd like on their computer. How would I be able to do that? I'm using Xcode 8.1, Swift 3, and making a macOS Cocoa application. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1):

1. Use `NSSavePanel` to obtain the destination URL from the user
2. Use `NSBundle` to obtain the source URL in your app bundle
3. Use `NSFileManager` to copy the file

If once you've read the documentation, or written some code, you get stuck ask a new question showing where you've got to and what your problem is.

HTH